# Customize email subject in WooCommerce with vendor store-name (Dokan)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, dokan

We found this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320924/woocommerce-order-processing-email-subject-not-changing and it's working fine. We now want to extend this by display the vendor on a order in the order completed mail.

But we are not able to output the vendor store name.

Is there a obvious error in our code?

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order',

```
'change_completed_email_subject', 1, 2 );
function change_completed_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
global $woocommerce;

// Order ID 
$order->get_items();
     
// Author id
$author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
// Shopname
$vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
$shop_name = $vendor->get_shop_name();

// Blogname
$blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

// Output subject
$subject = sprintf( '%s, Deine %s Bestellung (#%s) wurde versendet! Vendor: %s', $order->billing_first_name, $blogname, $order->get_order_number(), $shop_name );
return $subject;
}
```

---

**Update:**

I already tried to get the name via `$shop_name = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_shop_name();` but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The use of global `$woocommerce` is not necessary
- You use `$order->get_items();`, but don't do anything with it
- `$product` is not defined
- Use `$order->get_billing_first_name()` VS `$order->billing_first_name`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order( $subject, $order ) {
    // Empty array
    $shop_names = array();
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        $shop_name = $vendor->get_shop_name();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $shop_name = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_shop_name();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $shop_name, $shop_names ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $shop_names[] = $shop_name;
        }
    }

    // Blogname
    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    // Set subject
    $subject = sprintf( __( '%s, Deine %s Bestellung (#%s) wurde versendet! Vendor: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_billing_first_name(), $blogname, $order->get_order_number(), implode( ', ', $shop_names ) );

    // Return
    return $subject;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order', 10, 2 );
```